# SVG element overlapping previous sibling SVGs

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I have multiple SVGs positioned around the circle. The problem is every SVG is overlapping its previous sibling SVG which is causing click event to fire in the wrong shape. Technically it is right but from the user perspective, it is wrong.

Comment: actually the only solution I see is to use clip-path with your div to obtain this shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the capturing of click events in the `.shapes` div (which turn out to be the culprit), and only capture the events from svg children:

```
.shapes {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.shapes svg * {
  pointer-events: painted;
}
```

The click event still bubbles through the `<svg>`, and so the delegate event listener still works without change.

Comment: Awesome!!, Does all the browser support this?